# How to specialize a variadic template struct for particular number of template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

Take the following template struct:

```
template<int n, typename... Ts>
struct Widget {};
```

How to specialize it for cases where `sizeof...(Ts) == n`? E.g. `Widget<3, int, char>` should resolve to the primary template, but `Widget<3, int, char, double>` should resolve to the specialization.

I've tried using the usual SFINAE pattern, but the problem is that the template parameter pack must be the last template parameter, so it's not possible to insert a SFINAE check after `typename... Ts`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a helper class:

```
// for your primary template
template<int n, bool b, class... Ts>
struct Widget_impl {};

// for your specialization
template<class... Ts>
struct Widget_impl<sizeof...(Ts), true, Ts...> {};

template<int n, typename... Ts>
using Widget = Widget_impl<n, n == sizeof...(Ts), Ts...>;
```

In fact, your case can be done directly:

```
// for your primary template
template<int n, class... Ts>
struct Widget {};

// for your specialization
template<class... Ts>
struct Widget<sizeof...(Ts), Ts...> {};
```

Because the case when `sizeof...(Ts) == n` is already a specialization.

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert an SFINAE check after the `typename... Ts`, but you can insert it before:

```
template<typename AlwaysVoid, int n, typename... Ts>
struct WidgetImpl {};

// ...

template <int n, typename... Ts>
struct WidgetImpl<std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Ts) == n>, n, Ts...> {
    // ...
};
```

Then, you can just alias it:

```
template <int n, typename... Ts>
using Widget = WidgetImpl<void, n, Ts...>;
```